# java difference between two dates using only logic, no calender, date or similar

Tags: java, date, logic

this is what I've got so far, but all I get is zero for the output. I've tried for loops that are separate for the first year and last year to calculate just the months in those years then a separate for loop for the years inbetween since they would be full years and still I get the wrong output. I just need some guidance and as the title says I can't use calender or date or any other similar class just loops and logic.

```
package cop2250.spring18.week3.ledesma;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Week3assignment1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int days1 = 0, days2 = 0, days3 = 0, totalDays = 0, month3 = 0,         betweenYears, year3;

        System.out.println("Enter a starting Date in the format mm-dd-yyyy: ");
        String[] startDate = input.next().split("-");

        int month1 = Integer.parseInt(startDate[0]);
        int day1 = Integer.parseInt(startDate[1]);
        int year1 = Integer.parseInt(startDate[2]);

        System.out.println("Enter an ending Date in the format mm-dd-yyyy: ");
        String[] endDate = input.next().split("-");

        int month2 = Integer.parseInt(endDate[0]);
        int day2 = Integer.parseInt(endDate[1]);
        int year2 = Integer.parseInt(endDate[2]);


        for(year3 = 0; year3 > year1 && year3 < year2; year3++) {
            for (month3 = 0; month3 < 12; month3++) {
                days1 = daysInMonth(year3, month3);

            }
                totalDays =+ days1;
        }

        System.out.println("Days is : "+ totalDays);


    }
    private static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        return year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 || year % 100 == 0);   
        }   
    private static int daysInMonth(int year, int month) {
        if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12)
            return 31;
        if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
            return 30;
        if (month == 2)
            return isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you entering a date smaller than 0 (zero)?. Otherwise `year3 = 0; year3 > year1` will never be `true` and your loop will never enter.

Comment: I've tried year3 = year1 and I still get a wrong output.

Comment: `=+` is not a valid operator, or at least it's not doing what you think it is. You probably want `+=`. There are other issues with your code, though.

Comment: Well, after `year3 = year1` the condition `year3 > year1` is most certainly `false`; they're exclusive after all. I'm avoiding to answer this question directly, because the requirement indicates that it might be a homework question. If this assumption is correct, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48672687/edit) your question to clarify what we are allowed to do within the policies of your assignment.

Comment: It is an assignment, and I know what I have to do, the main point being methods, which I have down. I just can't get the loops to work so that they add up the days for each month.  Unless I'm totally off track and I need to be using a different type of loop.

Comment: I apologize for my inaccurate wording. By 'what we are allowed to do' I meant how the StackOverflow community is allowed to help you. In most cases this excludes directly pointing out the solution.

Comment: Oh I see, the main thing was the methods

Answer (score 1):

I see some issues here:

The outer loop starts from 0, shouldn't it start from year1?

The inner loop numbers months from 0 to 11 but the method you call numbers them from 1 to 12.

x =+ y is quite different from x += y.

If I give a date in 2016 and one in 2017 it looks to me like you are counting the days of all the months in those two years. So the inner loop also need to consider the given months (and days):

Comment: Ok, i see that, would it work better if I made separate loops for the starting year, the ending year and the years in between?